# Need help to find code error to send AT command response in sms

Tags: programming, code-review

I know that there is something wrong in my code bellow because I don't get "OK" as response in the SMS when I use Serial.print ("AT") . "AT" is an AT command.
I am using the example 2 of http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=396450.0

I tested the code bellow on the serial monitor and I am able to see the response of the AT commands on the serial monitor with Debug.println(receivedChars);. However, I am unable to receive the command's response in the SMS and would like to know what is wrong in this procedure. When I upload this code bellow, I only see "AT" in the SMS without the "OK". I think that SW_Serial.print(receivedChars); should show give OK in the SMS but I don't see it.Do you kmow why?

Comment: The full code is very long but my error can be found in the part of the code which I gave

Comment: I replaced the older code by the new one which is more complete . It includes the setup and the includes. Can you tell me why I don't get "OK" response in SMS ?

Comment: It is disrespectful to change your question to gibberish. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You are making the mistake of hoping the serial response will come very quickly. You are checking for serial available, which is good, but the function PrintModemResponse gives up once no serial is available. This is quite likely to be before all of the data has arrived. Imagine you are listening to me talking, and you assume that if there is a brief pause (as I take a breath) that my sentence is over. You are better off reading until you get a definite "end marker" like a newline.

I notice you are doing something like that in recvWithEndMarker.

You may find my page about [how to process incoming serial data without blocking](http://www.gammon.com.au/serial) helpful. Example code from that page:

```
/*
Example of processing incoming serial data without blocking.

Author:   Nick Gammon
Date:     13 November 2011. 
Modified: 31 August 2013.

Released for public use.
*/

// how much serial data we expect before a newline
const unsigned int MAX_INPUT = 50;

void setup ()
  {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  } // end of setup

// here to process incoming serial data after a terminator received
void process_data (const char * data)
  {
  // for now just display it
  // (but you could compare it to some value, convert to an integer, etc.)
  Serial.println (data);
  }  // end of process_data

void processIncomingByte (const byte inByte)
  {
  static char input_line [MAX_INPUT];
  static unsigned int input_pos = 0;

  switch (inByte)
    {

    case '\n':   // end of text
      input_line [input_pos] = 0;  // terminating null byte

      // terminator reached! process input_line here ...
      process_data (input_line);

      // reset buffer for next time
      input_pos = 0;  
      break;

    case '\r':   // discard carriage return
      break;

    default:
      // keep adding if not full ... allow for terminating null byte
      if (input_pos < (MAX_INPUT - 1))
        input_line [input_pos++] = inByte;
      break;

    }  // end of switch

  } // end of processIncomingByte  

void loop()
  {
  // if serial data available, process it
  while (Serial.available () > 0)
    processIncomingByte (Serial.read ());

  // do other stuff here like testing digital input (button presses) ...

  }  // end of loop
```

Comment: do you mean like that my PrintModemResponse should be like this (answer under your post)?

Comment: Please amend your question to clarify it. Answers are for answering the question, not clarifying what other people have told you.

Comment: Please tell me if my new PrintModemResponse called PrintModemResponse2 from the new full code is ok ?  It still doesn't give me the right thing. Do you know how I could improve it ?

Comment: It's not any better because as soon as available has 0 it doesn't matter what flagend is, the while loop will still exit before you get the whole thing.

Comment: Your code in `GetModemResponse` does not wait for a newline. I suggest you read the link I gave above. You seem to have three or four functions, all of which rather confusingly get a response from the modem. One should be plenty.

Comment: For the function GetModemResponse, can it really affect the response that it doesn't wait for the newline and since I am calling it only once and it's in the void setup() ?. I implemented your function from the link instead of my function PrintModemResponse() as we can see in the main code which I replaced. However, I still don't get the desired reply. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you post some output from this program?  There are a lot of debugging prints going on in there and it might help to see what is going on.  Are you not getting the response you want in setup?  Or are you talking about a response in loop?  Is the code making it to loop at all?

Comment: Wait, you're receiving that on the cellphone?  I thought we were talking about the Arduino receiving something.  Now I'm confused.

Comment: OK, please stop and explain the big picture of what it is that we're working on and what it is supposed to do and how it is supposed to work.  All through that whole ordeal over on the Arduino board I thought you were trying to receive an OK on the Arduino.

Comment: "Does anyone know whyI don't get OK response always? "

Yes, we know that's the question.  You don't have to keep repeating it over and over.  What you need to do instead is clarify it.

Comment: I said this in the first post: However, I am unable to receive the command's response in the SMS... What does that mean to you? and in that case Why did you think that it's only on the Arduino ?

Comment: I didn't think it was only on the Arduino.  I thought the "OK" you wanted to receive on the Arduino.  Now I'm not sure what you think is sending what where.  To me it looked like you posted Arduino code.  Does that code actually run on the phone?  Or the Arduino?

Comment: And no you haven't described what this setup is.  You jumped straight into what you thought the code problem is.  I'm looking for the big picture idea.  Like, "this is a project to allow my Arduino to tell my phone to call my mom if I get lost" or whatever it is actually supposed to do.  Help me understand what you have actually set up.  Remember, nobody here can see it.